# Two problems with the Activity settings in Android

Tags: android, settings

I have two roughly connected issues in my new Android app regarding the Settings. The former is the need to retrieve the information from the preferences without displaying the specific setting activity by performing some:

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
```

in another activity.

Is it possible to do it or how else may I retrieve the data without displaying the activity, or is it possible to start the activity without displaying it?

The latter more distressing one is that even in the SettingActivity, when I call that function I recently started getting a crash complaining:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Float cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Like if something internal were set somehow expecting something. What may I do and in particular how may I reset this sort of hidden structure?
This is my xml file: if I just keep the entries in the former category it does not crash, if I add any field in the latter it does:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<PreferenceCategory 
    android:title="@string/switches"
    android:key="switches">
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="night_switch_start"
        android:summary="@string/ext_night_switch_start"
        android:defaultValue="22"
        android:title="@string/night_switch_start" />
    <EditTextPreference 
        android:key="day_switch_start"
        android:summary="@string/ext_day_switch_start"
        android:defaultValue="6"
        android:title="@string/day_switch_start"/>
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory 
    android:title="@string/tokens"
    android:key="tokens">
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="token_day"
        android:summary="@string/ext_token_day"
        android:defaultValue="3"
        android:title="@string/token_day" />
</PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Thanks, Fabrizio

Comment: Is there any reason you can't used Android's SharedPreferenes? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: In fact I used them, but for some reason I am not able to read all the vales from the xml file. Assuming they come from there and not from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

For you first question, you can retrieve a preference saved in a `PreferenceActivity` by calling `PreferenceManager#getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context)`. This is a static method, so you can have in your `Activity` something like:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

About your second question, I'm not sure what is happening. Try cleaning the project before you run it again.

Comment: The `getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context)` is a static method, and so you can call `PreferenceManager#getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)` if you're inside an `Activity`. I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: My problem is retrieving the values in the xml settings, not the ones in the normal sharedPreferences. Your function retrieves the latter and I am quite proficient in doing it. Of course I might have made some confusion between the two; I come from iOS where there is just a single repository.

Comment: Also, when I excute: Log.d(LOG_TAG, "shared "+sharedPref.toString()); once I found the values in the normal settings (I think...), and now I just get: android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl@41e0dd18 . This thing has a life of its own...

Comment: What do you mean by "xml settings"? Every setting inside `preferences.xml` is saved to a XML accessible by using my answer above. You can them call methods like `getAll()`, `getInt(String key, int defValue)` and so on to get a value from a specific setting.
About `sharedPref.toString()`, every Java class can override `Object#toString()` to return what it makes sense in that particular class. The default implementation simply returns the class name and its memory address.

Comment: I wish it were true. Yet my preferences xml sit there and sharedPref= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Dashboard.dashboard); //becca quelle ordinarie
   Log.d(LOG_TAG, "shared "+sharedPref.toString());
   startDayTime=Integer.parseInt(sharedPref.getString("day_switch_start", ""));startNightTime=Integer.parseInt(sharedPref.getString("night_switch_start", "")); loads the first string but not the latter. Not to mention the SettingActivity abruptly crashing on addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences); I suspect the problem is in the xml but I ignore what it might be.

Comment: As for the toString() function, you may believe me or not, but the first time I tried it returned the contents of the preferences. Or I think so, this thing is extremely confusing.

Comment: Please share more of your code to let us understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I answer here to be able to show my code better: this is the first summarizing part of the xml file I suspect might have problems:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<PreferenceCategory 
    android:title="@string/switches"
    android:key="switches">
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="night_switch_start"
        android:summary="@string/ext_night_switch_start"
        android:defaultValue="22"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:title="@string/night_switch_start" />
    <EditTextPreference 
        android:key="day_switch_start"
        android:summary="@string/ext_day_switch_start"
        android:defaultValue="6"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:title="@string/day_switch_start"/>
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory 
    android:title="@string/tokens"
    android:key="switches">
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="token_day"
        android:summary="@string/ext_token_day"
        android:defaultValue="3"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:title="@string/token_day" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

My code is very simple: the crashing setting part is the following.

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
private static final String LOG_TAG = "preferences";
public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
...
}
```

While the code loading the string and finding "mostly" empty strings is:

```
sharedPref= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Dashboard.dashboard); 
startDayTime=Integer.parseInt(sharedPref.getString("day_switch_start", "")); //correct value
startNightTime=Integer.parseInt(sharedPref.getString("night_switch_start", "")); //empty string thereafter rising an exception.
```

Also, when I tried leaving just the first two EditText, so not to have the crash, the Setting activity had the correct value for day_switch_start and again an empty string in the night_switch_start field.

When I do getAll() I get the correct values:

```
{start_night_time=6, day_switch_start=6, notifications_new_message_ringtone=content://settings/system/notification_sound, notifications_new_message=true, second_rate_limit=24.0, third_rate_fare=1.6, token_day=6.0, token_night=6.0, night_switch_start=22, token_holiday=6.0, start_day_time=6, start_night_switch=John Smith, example_checkbox=true, example_text=John Smith, notifications_new_message_vibrate=false, example_list=-1, first_rate_fare=1.1, first_rate_limit=11.0, max_speed_for_time=20.0, sync_frequency=180, second_rate_fare=1.3, timed_fares=27.0, cooperative=}
```

Yet, when I try to get the value of them either with:

```
startDayTime=Integer.parseInt(sharedPref.getString("night_switch_start", "")); or
startNightTime=sharedPref.getInt("night_switch_start", 0);
```

I retrieve an empty string in both cases.

Comment: That part of the XML is well formed. Are you using any other Widget which is storing something as float (maybe `second_rate_limit`, `third_rate_fare`, `first_rate_fare`, `second_rate_fare`...)? How are you trying to retrieve it? I created an example project loading your XML above and it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Half of the answer: clearing the cache of the phone removes all the funny fields and does not crash any longer the setting activity, nor the loading of its values by:

```
startNightTime=Integer.parseInt(sharedPref.getString("night_switch_start", ""));
```

The old form:

```
startNightTime=sharedPref.getInt("night_switch_start", 0);
```

still crashes, notwithstanding the values seem numeral. Not a big deal, though.

The unanswered problem is how to load the settings from the xml file without entering the SettingsActivity performing:

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
```

Is it possible to run the function from outside that activity or is it possible to start the activity without visualizing it to the user?